# How to erase Time Machine backups in trash?

Tags: time-machine, backup, macos, time-capsule, trash

I have a lot of backup data from TM (>800Gb) in my trash and I can't delete it. Trying everything what I find in "AskDifferent" & also [this](https://seo-michael.co.uk/how-to-remove-os-x-time-machine-backups-from-trash/). It's too long - over 2 hours left and nothing! I can not recover these backup folders or delete them one by one. 
Maybe I should use Disk Utility and erase `Time Machine` property (it's under `MacBook Pro.sparsebundle` directory, not `Time Capsule`, where there are other files)? I need to save info in my TC, only erase backups in trash and others.
[image]

Please help...

Comment: did you try holding the option key?

Comment: Yes, sure - also too long and errors during the process.

Comment: Did you try `Erase Disk` option in `Airport Utility` program?

Comment: Nope, because it will delete all info in my TC and I need to erase only my backups in TM. Or just clean my trash (that'll be great).

Comment: and the Delete backup in the Time machine does not work ?

Comment: No, they all (5 backup folders) stay in trash and delete them all is unpossible, I'm waiting for my terminal, which delete info from trash one by one file and now it's stuck.

Comment: It takes long time! no wonder! Even at 160 Gb/Hour with USB3 or Thunderbolt connection it will take 5 hours to delete from Time machine. I assume your TM is not in your trash. And due to your manual delete your TM might have become fragmented that does not add to the speed.

Comment: Unfortunately I have only wi-fi connection, so it's too complicated. Can I use the Disk Utility and try to erase all info from my TC (like in screenshot), what I'll get in the end?